# MySql Database didnot upload data its give this error

Tags: sqlalchemy, mysql

SQL query:

```
  INSERT INTO `lance_attachments` (`file_id`, `file_name`, `file_content`, `file_type`, `file_size`)
    VALUES (19, 'P1010147.JPG', 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[...]
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

i cannot upload my database on my wamp server it show this error
Help 
I have already change my maximum size and timeout

Comment: How big is the data you are trying to post?

Comment: check that your request is not bigger than [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it choked on the size of the SQL statement which exceeds some limit.

Try loading the data by not using SQL and using a [LOAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'somefile' INTO lance_attatchments
```

If your data doesn't have all the columns, create a view on the table that has only the columns you have dara for and load into the view.

Answer (score 0):

a very low default setting of max_allowed_packet - could be a reason. Raising max_allowed_packet in my.cnf (under [mysqld]) to 8 or 16M usually fixes it.

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=16M
```

OR

If you have a query that is causing a timeout you can set this variable by executing:

```
SET @@GLOBAL.wait_timeout=300;
SET @@LOCAL.wait_timeout=300;  -- OR current session only
```

Where 300 is the number of seconds you think the maximum time the query could take.